# Amazon CloudFront handshake exception on manual clock change

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have suddenly noticed something that is causing an issue with my application, I have assets on S3 with CloudFront distribution on them which users can download upon demand. 
For some reason, if an Android user changes the time on his clock to the future manually (removes automatic date and time) the handshake with CloudFront fails.
Has anyone encountered something like this? is there a known reason or fix?

Comment: Do you have CloudFront or S3 signed URLs ? What error do you get ? Generally, in S3 sigv4 signed url (if you're using it), you get 403 if the time difference is more than 5 mins.

Comment: This is an example of the error on one of our public files: 01-17 12:42:57.226: E/Unity(31719): WWW download had an error:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed at url:https://xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/Android/folder/6/scene.unity3d --- it doesn't happen on all devices and I took 2 different galaxy S8 devices and changed their date to a month from now, one managed to download and the other one didn't. I've contacted amazon and the certificate seems up to date on the cloudfront side.

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3180